# Moving variables that are not pointers?

Tags: c++, move

My question is that if we want to move an object and inside that object the variable we want to move is not a pointer, how should we release the temporary value?

Should I assign the memory of the temporary variable to nullptr? (Which is not even possible)

Here is the code for better understanding

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ...

    Foo(Foo&& other) noexcept
    {
        m_Value = other.m_Value;

        /*
        The bottom line will not work, so what should I do instead of this line of code?
        */
        &other.m_Value = nullptr;
    }
private:
    int m_Value;
};
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that you need to do anything, at all? What does "release the temporary value" mean?

Comment: An `int` is just a number, it can't be null or have some other funny value. You either leave it unchanged or set it to some predictable value, depending on what the class is doing. Do you actually need a custom move constructor here?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I meant the member of the rvalue that was supposed to move

Comment: For plain types like `int`, moving it means to copy the value and leave the original value in a valid but indeterminate state. So the first assignment is really enough.

Comment: @TheParhamDev A move shouldn't affect the storage of the moved-from object. Moves are non-destructive.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Now I see

Comment: Note that `m_Value = other.m_Value;` will make a copy. You still need `std::move()` if you really want to move from `other`.

Comment: @Evg Oh, you're right, I had completely forgotten about this

Comment: @Evg Not really, all [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) does is cast the value into an rvalue reference. It doesn't actually *move* anything.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude We all know this.

Comment: `other.m_Value = int{};` or `other.m_Value = decltype(other.m_Value){};` or *nothing* because it is now in a valid-but-unspecified state (if that what **you** want **your** `Foo` move contract to be), or something else that you consider appropriate for your program.

Comment: @Evg Your comment makes it seem like the OP should be using  `m_Value = std:move(other.m_Value)` which really doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Evg Wait a second, isn't this what we have to do to move?

Comment: If the type of `m_Value` is indeed `int`, then there is nothing to move and using `move()` is redundant. In a more general case, when `m_Value` has a movable type (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`), then you'll need `std::move()`.

Comment: You should first ask yourself why we need `other.m_Value = nullptr` when `m_Value` **is** a pointer.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah I know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of the move constructor, while it *may* be a temporary, is going to be valid throughout your move constructor's body. So, it's **not** your responsibility to clean up after it; it will be managed automatically. All you need to worry about is copying or moving each individual member from `other` so that your object is properly constructed.

In your example, you only need to initialize `m_Value` which is an `int`. `int`s are trivially copyable, so just a simple assignment is all you can do (of course in this particular example that's going to be the behavior of the default move constructor as well).

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    ...

    Foo(Foo&& other) noexcept {
        m_Value = other.m_Value;
    }

private:
    int m_Value;
};
```

If your class contains types of other classes that aren't trivially copyable, such as `std::string` (which has to manage its own dynamically allocated memory for the string), it's a good idea to use `std::move` to trigger its move constructor (again the following example is too simple and a default move constructor would suffice again).

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    ...

    Foo(Foo&& other) noexcept {
        m_Value = std::move(other.m_Value); // Trigger the move assignment of m_Value instead of a copy
    }
private:
    std::string m_Value;
};
```

And a final note, to avoid the assignment in the constructor (which requires the class members being default initialized prior to construction), it's a good idea to initialize them as such to use the move constructor directly:

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    /* Initializing members before the constructor body */
    Foo(Foo&& other) noexcept : m_Value1(other.m_value1), m_Value2(std::move(other.m_Value2)) {}

private:
    int m_Value1;
    std::string m_Value2;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

### Not using Pointers

Since `m_Value` is not a pointer, you won't need to set it to null because it's just an int (i.e. a variable that, in this case, can only hold integers), here's an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Foo* other = nullptr)
    {
        if (other != nullptr)
        {
            m_Value = other->m_Value;
    
            // Just remove the line.
            //other->m_Value = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            m_Value = 2;
        }
    }
    
    int m_Value;
};

int main()
{
    Foo a;
    Foo b(a);
    
    std::cout << b.m_Value;
    
    return 0;
}

// OUTPUT: 2
```

### Using Pointers

Even though you specified that you don't want to use pointers, they are always a good feature to know when having to transfer big chunks of data.

For example, if `m_Value` would be a big class with a lot of data it would be better to transfer the variable pointing to it than the entire class.

Here's an example that makes the `foo` class able to set the `m_Value` variable to nullptr:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Foo* other = nullptr)
    {
        if (other != nullptr)
        {
            m_Value = other->m_Value;
    
            // Set m_Value to nullptr after transporting its value to ours.
            other->m_Value = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            m_Value = new int(2);
            
            // It's the same as:
            // m_Value = 2;
            // But for pointers.
        }
    }
    
    ~Foo()
    {
        delete m_Value;
    }
    
    int* m_Value = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    Foo a;
    Foo b(&a);
    
    // The * operator takes the value '2' from the pointer m_Value.
    std::cout << *b.m_Value;
    
    return 0;
}

// OUTPUT: 2
```

As you can see, other than the code being lengthier, the `foo` class now makes full use of C++'s pointers.

As mentioned before, the code you wrote didn't work because `m_Value` wasn't a pointer but just an int, it could hold just integers numbers and not variable addresses.

Making `m_Value` an int* i.e. a pointer containing an address pointing to an integer, will fix the problem,
you are now able to set `m_Value` to nullptr, but you'll have to follow pointers rules like allocating and deleting the pointers when you're done using them.

You can check [W3 School tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_pointers.asp) on C++ pointers if you want to know more.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suspect it is because your answer does not answer the question posed about moving variables **that are not pointers**.

Comment: I modified the answer, the old version was, in fact, wrong. C++ is a huge language and it allows various solutions to problems. So it wouldn't make sense for me to force the use of pointers even if you specified that you didn't want to use them in the first place. I hope the edit solves your issue.

Comment: The first example is weird. The constructor you define is used as a default constructor (with `other` being `nullptr`), not as a copy one. The code inside `if (other != nullptr)` branch is never called.

Comment: @Evg This is to make the construction of a `foo` class with its variable possible. Since it couldn't be feasible to call the code in main without the other variable as a reference, creating a class `a` of type `foo` would need another class reference that would need another class reference, and so forth. So I made the `other` argument default to nullptr and the script `if (other != nullptr)` to be run at the creation of `b`.

Comment: `Foo b(a);` won't call `Foo(Foo*)` constructor at all.

Comment: I added std::cout's to the code and uploaded the code on [gdb](https://onlinegdb.com/SIaBBTY5k), maybe I didn't understand your comment right but the `m_Value = new int(2);` is called so the `Foo(Foo*)` constructor should be called on `b`'s creation.